# Unity on linux (some versions) parsing 1.00 like 100

Tags: json, unity-game-engine, floating-point, local

I using Unity JsonConvert.DeserializeObject to load my saves as a class. It works on Win and Mac, but on SOME versions of Linux, unity parsing float 1.00 like 100, and -0.05 as 0. Is it depends on local?

Maybe someone knows how to avoid and it inside unity, or has a universal floating format. Please give a hint without changing to another JSON serializer if it is possible.

Thanks

Comment: Use `JsonUtility` instead of `JsonConvert`. Next time time you are going to ask a json question, post the json, the class and the script you are using to de-serialize the json.

Comment: JsonUtility requires to create a wrapper for each list, isn't it?

Comment: No. Not for each list. One wrapper from the duplicate is enough. Are you using newtonsoft?

Comment: yes, I am using newtonsoft

Comment: Edit and post the json, the class and the script you are using to de-serialize the json. Before you do that, there is a special newtonsoft  version for Unity. It is linked in the duplicate if you look there. Make sure you are using that version of newtonsoft .